# How to create Content type in SharePoint using MSGraph api

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to create a SharePoint Content Type through MS Graph, like this `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/ContentTypes`? It seams that there are a lot of working endpoints that are not in the documentation.

Comment: What did you get when you tried it?

Comment: Failure - Status Code 404

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3123f64a-3e7a-4cc4-8222-4286a339a67e",
            "date": "2018-03-22T14:40:15"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I try to send something like this {
  "id": "0x010100FA0963FA69A646AA916D2E41284FC9D2",
  "parentId": "0x0101",
  "name": "New CT"
}